# CSS3 checkbox styling

Tags: css, checkbox

I have no experience with checkbox styling. Is there anyway to achieve border radius effect on checkboxes? How can I style checkbox like this image?

[image]

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/

Comment: Googled your exact title and got several good alternatives. Such as http://csscheckbox.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css

Comment: Associate a label to every checkboxe, hide the checkbox part and style the label as you want. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879084/making-a-div-like-radio-button/18879818#18879818

Answer (score 8):

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox">  
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">  
        <label for="check1">Checkbox No. 1</label>  
        <br>  
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2">  
        <label for="check2">Checkbox No. 2</label>  
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content:"\2713";
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

As seen [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zbX4/)

What it should look like in modern browsers.
[image: What it should look like]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vGja8/ is the code that you posted. it doesn't give any result similiar to image I posted

Comment: @heron It does. See my added fiddle. I didn't post all the needed CSS thoughn but I added some more.

Comment: Neither past answer nor updated doesn't give anything visually similiar to image I posted. Re-read my question please

Comment: @heron You wanted to style your checkboxes, and add border radius? Well, my code does that. Unless you are looking at the fiddle in an old browser. see my added screenshot.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/UM6bRdhAj2c I need to achieve this result

Comment: @heron this gets you very close. You have not shown any efort at solving this yourself. This is a good answer and if you know anything about CSS two or three changes to the CSS will give you exactly what you need. The more effort you put in the more effort we will put in. Don't expect to get something for nothing.

Comment: These checkboxes are not tabbable though - right?

Comment: @Dannyboy They sure are clickable, so I presume they can be used on touch devices as well. It's pure CSS, so it should work I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="square">
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="square" name="check" />
<label for="square"></label></div>
```

css3 code:

```
.square label {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 left: 4px;
 top: 4px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 0px white;
 border:1px solid lightblue;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 100%);

   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );   }

  .square label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
     height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px; 
     left: 4px;
      border: 3px solid blue;
      border-top: none;
     border-right: none;

     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
         transform: rotate(-45deg);  }

 .square input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
       filter: alpha(opacity=100);
         opacity: 1; }
```

i am modifying css code...check it

Comment: here is the code that you posted http://jsfiddle.net/6zbX4/1/ . http://screencast.com/t/FDbB2WJy5L4f why right side border looks like that?

Comment: ya. you change background-color to white.border color to light blue.

Comment: heron check this modified code.    and add this  property border-radius:2px; in square label class. ok