# using a div element as a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building a site where I prefered to use a div element as a checkbox.
If selected the checkbox class is toggled using javascript.

Heres the html.

```
<div class='col span_1_of_6 menuGroup'>
    <div class="circl3" style="background-image:url(images/icons/'.$icon.') background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
    <p class='menuGroupName'>$items</p>
</div>
```

`$icon` (an icon for the item) & `$items` (item name) are php to fetch from mysqli db. I originally used entire html in php echo. But, for better reading I posted like that.

Here's the javascript.

```
$(".menuGroup").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("btnOn");
});
```

Here is the div element in 2 states. Selected and Not Selected.
http://postimg.org/image/5sk0z4tgj/

WHAT I WANT is the `<p>` element name to be submited to the next page when i click the Submit Button
And is there is a better alternative to this method?

Comment: What do you mean by `<p> element name`? `<p>` tags don't have the `name` attribute.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Item name ($items) should be submitted. Sorry again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 checkbox styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973095/css3-checkbox-styling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make hidden checkbox and add `onchange` handler to change state of your pseudo checkbox.
Hidden checkbox will submit to the next page.

OR

See the CSS3 only [examples](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles) how to make it with out javascript.

Comment: Yes. I thought about that possibility. But is there any other possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see every element and pick up the selected ones and send the response

```
$('.menuGroup').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('btnOn')) {
        // Save element to send
    }
});
```